# Access-Control-Allow-Origin for http & https

Tags: javascript, iis, xmlhttprequest, web-config

Following javascript XMLHttpRequest is working when accessing the site with https:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET", "https://site/api/status", true);
xhttp.withCredentials = true;
xhttp.send();
```

The web.config for the requested site is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="https://intranet.company.local" />
                    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
                    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type,Cache-Control,Pragma,Expires,Authorization" />
                    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

It should now also be possible to use the site with http also it is not secure. It is working if I change the XMLHttpRequest URL to "http://site/api/status" and the Access-Control-Allow-Origin to "http://intranet.company.local".

It is also not a problem to change the XMLHttpRequest URL based on the given protocol, but I cannot find a working web.config configuration to allow both protocols as the wildcard value for Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not working when using credentials.

Comment: obviously you won't be able to use hard coded `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` - that header will need to be done in code to reflect the protocol schema used in the request - or perhaps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/cors-module/cors-module-configuration-reference will help ... many other possibilities from searching *iis access-control-allow-origin with credentials*

Comment: @JaromandaX can you post this as an own post so I can mark it as the answer? Used the cors module and it is working great. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you solved your problem? If you have solved it, please post the answer so that it can help others with similar problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thansk to @Jaromanda X for the help. I used his reference from the iis cors module ([Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/cors-module/cors-module-configuration-reference))
to solve the problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <cors enabled="true" failUnlistedOrigins="true">
            <add origin="*" allowed="false"/>
            <add origin="https://intranet.company.local" allowCredentials="true"> 
                <allowHeaders allowAllRequestedHeaders="true" />
                <allowMethods>
                     <add method="GET" />
                </allowMethods>
            </add>
            <add origin="http://intranet.company.local" allowCredentials="true">
                <allowHeaders allowAllRequestedHeaders="true" />
                <allowMethods>
                     <add method="GET" />
                </allowMethods>
            </add>
        </cors>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```